# iPhone - sending a message "in the air" for any listener object

Tags: iphone, notifications, message

Is there a way onto the iPhone for an object to send a message without a specific receiver object, and into another object, listen to such messages, that could come with objects (parameters), and do what is needed ?

I searched around NSNotification but I don't see what I should do.

Comment: Do you mean between two phones running the same app?

Comment: @deanWombourne : no, I mean inside one app. Post edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects that want to be notified need to register to receive notifications with the notification center. Thereafter, when a notification is posted to the notification center, the notification center will check it against all the registered filters, and the corresponding action will be taken for each matching filter.

A "filter" in this case is the pair of (notification name, notification object). A `nil` object in the filter is equivalent to any object (the notification object is ignored in matching). The name is required.

Example:

```
/* Subscribe to be sent -noteThis:
 * whenever a notification named @"NotificationName" is posted to the center
 * with any (or no) object. */
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(noteThis:)
           name:@"NotificationName"
         object:nil];

/* Post a notification. */
[nc postNotificationName:@"NotificationName" object:self userInfo:someDict];

/* Handle a notification. */
- (void)noteThis:(NSNotification *)note
{
   id object = [note object];
   NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
   /* take some action */
}
```

There is a more modern API using queues and blocks, but I find the old API easier to illustrate and explain.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you post a notification (NSNotification) to the shared class, `NSNotificationCenter`. Here's an example:

```
#define kNotificationCenter [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
#define kNotificationToSend @"a notification name as a string"

//... Post the notification 

[kDefaultCenter postNotificationNamed:knotificationToSend withObject:nil];
```

Any class that wants to listen, adds itself as an *observer* to the notifcation center. You must remove the observer as well.

```
[kNotificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodToHandleNotification) object:nil];

//... Usually in the dealloc or willDisappear method:

[kNotificationCenter removeObserver:self];
```

You can do more with the notification center. See [the NSNotificationCenter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/) fr complete reference.

Comment: Thank you. I was on the right way. But what about sending an object as parameter ? What should be listened ?

Comment: Listening for an object is just a filter to listen for *only* a given object. If you listen for a nil object, all notifications with the matching name will work.  When posting, you can send an object and/or an NSDictionary. See the documentation for more.

Answer (score 0):

I think `NSNotification` is the message object itself, to send to listen to what is sent try `NSNotificationCenter`. It has a singleton object, so to send the message:

```
NSNotification *notificationObj;
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center postNotification:notificationObj];
```

And the other class listen to with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method:) object:nil];
```

Make sure that class has `method:` method. You can have a single parameter, which is an `NSNotification` object that is sent earlier. The `NSNotification` object has `[notificationObj object` which you can get as a piece of data sent by the sender class. Alternatively, you might use `[notificationObj userInfo]` if you want it to be more structured.

you can initialise `notificationObj` and tailor it with the message that you'd want. More information on `NSNotificationCenter`, you can find it

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNotificationCenter

or for more information about `NSNotification` itself

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html